# Does the Maker contract have a recovery function in his contract for funds sent to his address?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Is there a function inside of the Maker contract: https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&p=2 that would allow to recover funds that are sent to the contract address?

If not, why did Binance made transfers similar to this one: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa2dd7e8654551be012381f7d13c0ba6c5439f4230dd76d738987e4c4dc8f8d42

Answer (score 1):

There should be some way that the contract sends the funds back or to somebody as if you take a look over here: [Page 3 of Transaction History](https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&p=3) of the same contract, you will find an **OUT** transaction, which shows that it can be sent back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I see that OUT transaction are quite more rare, so not all IN transactions are done with that purpose in mind I guess